# Failure to scaffold a MySQL database into my .net core Web API project

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I used nuget to add these to my project:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design v 7.0.1
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql v 6.0.2

and scaffolding with:
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold Name=NorthwindDB Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql --output-dir Models --context-dir Data --namespace Northwind.Models --context-namespace Northwind.Data --context NorthwindContext -f --no-onconfiguring

I end up with the following errors

```
Scaffolding fails with the following output:
C:\Northwind.MySQL\Northwind.MySQL\Northwind.MySQL.csproj : error NU1107: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational. Install/reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 7.0.1 directly to project Northwind.MySQL to resolve this issue. 
C:\Northwind.MySQL\Northwind.MySQL\Northwind.MySQL.csproj : error NU1107:  Northwind.MySQL -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 7.0.1 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 7.0.1) 
C:\Northwind.MySQL\Northwind.MySQL\Northwind.MySQL.csproj : error NU1107:  Northwind.MySQL -> Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 6.0.2 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 6.0.7 && < 7.0.0).

Build FAILED.

C:\Northwind.MySQL\Northwind.MySQL\Northwind.MySQL.csproj : error NU1107: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational. Install/reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 7.0.1 directly to project Northwind.MySQL to resolve this issue. 
C:\Northwind.MySQL\Northwind.MySQL\Northwind.MySQL.csproj : error NU1107:  Northwind.MySQL -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 7.0.1 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 7.0.1) 
C:\Northwind.MySQL\Northwind.MySQL\Northwind.MySQL.csproj : error NU1107:  Northwind.MySQL -> Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 6.0.2 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 6.0.7 && < 7.0.0).
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

I tried adding a reference to the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational dll in my dependencies, but I got the same error.

I tried different versions of of the dependencies, I'm at my wits end.
Has anyone successfully done this kind of scaffolding using the pomelo lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project Northwind.MySQL has the dependencies and sub dependencies :

- **Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 6.0.2**

  - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 6.0.7 && < 7.0.0)
- **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 7.0.1**

  - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational > 7.0.1

The project Northwind.MySQL has the dependency Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql at version 6 that need the dependency **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational at version 6**.

Also the project Northwind.MySQL has the dependency Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design at version 7 that need the dependency **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational at version 7**.

The project Northwind.MySQL need indirectly the dependency **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational** at version 6 and 7... that isn't possible.

The solution is to manage the root dependencies that the sub dependencies match.

You can downgrade EF Core to version 6 like :

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design --version 6.0.12
```

Or update Pomelo to version 7 (actually in beta) :

```
dotnet add package Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql --version 7.0.0-silver.1
```